# Can get ejs file to render, im using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I would like to get my ejs file to display on the server      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  <html>
          <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
          <body>
            welcome <%= user%>;
          </body>
        </html>









    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        var express = require("express");
        var app = express();
        var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


        app.get("/", function(req, res){
                res.sendFile(__dirname + '/about.html');

        });

        app.get("/news", function(req, res){
                res.sendFile(__dirname + '/news.html');

        });

        //app.get('/student/:id', function(req, rep){
        //        rep.render('student', { name : student[req.params.id] , id : req.params.id});

        //});

        //app.get('/student', function(req, res) {
        //    res.render('student');
        //});

        app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
          res.render('student',{user:"John Smith"}) 
        }); 



        app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i would like to get the student.ejs file to display on the server

Comment: You have two mappings with the same route, do you want to use `/student ` for student?

Comment: yeah,            //////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting routes configured for `'/'`.

Do you want to use a separate route for student? like following

```
app.get('/student', function(req, res){ 
          res.render('student',{user:"John Smith"}) 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a `views` folder, and put your .ejs template in there.  For example if you create the file `views/student.ejs` , then you can use this route to render this ejs file

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    res.render('student', {user:"John Smith"}) 
});
```

[Scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)